# Regex pattern issue with Lightning Input in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I have been using regex pattern for some Lightning input field in LWC and also provided '**message-when-pattern-mismatch**' error message.

regex is like : `pattern="[a-zA-Z-]+"`

As per the pattern, input field will only accept alphabet in lowercase, uppercase  and hyphen.
But if I provide any special character or number then instead of showing error in the UI, its showing error in the console.

Again if I modify the regex like `pattern="[a-zA-Z\-]+"`
Now it shows pattern mismatch error in the UI.

Does anyone have any idea why it's happening suddenly? Previously it was working fine.

Comment: Putting the hyphen at the end of a character class doesn't work with some regex engines. Either put it at the start or escape it. Are you running the LWC on a different browser to what you have used before?

Comment: Also, you may need to double escape it: `\\-`

Comment: Hi @Phil, I haven't changed my browser. Can you check in your org by creating a simple component?

Comment: Hi @Casper, It was working fine without escaping. But now it's not. I just need to know the reason. Solution, I already have.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Could it be some updates in the browser itself?

Comment: I don't think so. I have tested with Microsoft edge as well as google chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an LWC-specific issue, but is caused by a change in the browser's pattern matching specifications.

There have been changes to the regular expression pattern matching options in Chromium.
https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/v8/v8/+/4212393

This change has been incorporated in Chrome 114.
https://chromestatus.com/feature/5149507107422208

Since Edge is also Chromium-based, it is likely that similar issues may arise.